# How to update python for all users in CentOS

Tags: centos

Good morning,

i have a simple questions for update packages to all users. I want to update python (and others)
Now when i run sh as root, i cant update python because its up to date with `python --version = Python 3.9.7`

Now i logged in as user. I try the command from above and i get: `Python 2.7.5` This user is not in the sudoers list so i cant update with `sudo yum install -y python3`

i have the same behaviour by other packages like node and so on.

How i can update python to all users?

Comment: How did you install python 3 as the root user? If you used `yum install python3`, it should be available for all users. Normally, the "python" command is linked to "python 2" even if "python3" was installed, due to legacy issues. This allows programs that still rely on python 2 to work. However, if you installed python 3 using a different method, there might be some environment configurations specific to your root user only (You can `echo $PATH` or `which python` to check on root user).

Comment: ok, now i found the difference. The root user is accessing the `/root/anaconda3/bin/python`, the user instead by this location `/usr/bin/python`